# AWS S3 Puts and EBS Volumes keep increasing

Tags: amazon-web-services, billing

I am using the free tier on AWS and I have this problem of S3-Puts and EBS-Volumes keep increasing despite the fact that I have no EBS-Volumes and my S3 being empty.  Does anyone have any idea on how I can stop this?  I have attached two screenshots from my bill
[image: First Check]
[image: Second Check]

Comment: You have an EC2 instance. Does it have any EBS volumes attached?

Comment: Delete your S3 buckets. That should stop the S3 puts.

Comment: I have actually deleted all the EC2 instances and EBS volumes and all the S3 buckets as well, I still dont know why this keeps increasing.

Comment: What did AWS Support say when you asked them?

Comment: I did not ask them anything yet, I thought I might get charged for that as well?

Comment: Ask on the AWS forums. It is their free support channel. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/